# How to read input from GUI in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, input, racket

I am writing a Mastermind program in Racket for my Programming Languages class. I have created a basic GUI to display information to the user. I want to ask the user "Do you wish to continue? Y/N", read their input from the GUI, and store that input into a string. I am new to Racket so if anyone can help me figure this out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/) for the GUI library?

Comment: Hi! I just created a simple text box to display information by defining a frame, editor-canvas and text. I used (define t (new text%)) and then (send t insert "Output Text") to display information in the GUI. But I don't know how to read an input. As I said I am completely new to Racket so I don't know much. I tried looking at the documentation but could not understand much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking the user for a Yes/No input, it is likely better to use a modal dialog. Luckily, `racket/gui` comes with a convenience function called [`message-box`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=message-box#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._message-box%29%29) that lets you do that:

```
(message-box "Title" "Do you wish to continue?" #f '(yes-no))
```

If you're sure that you want to ask the user for input using a text box, you probably want to use a [`text-field%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html) object (possibly with a `dialog%`) rather than a `text%` object. Take a look at the [widget gallery](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Widget_Gallery.html) in the docs to see what a `text-field%` looks like. You can set a callback on the field that will trigger when the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried doing taking input using a text box. I created a new text-field% object, but could not get any input back when I entered "Y" and Enter. Could you please tell me a little more on how to set a callback on the field that will trigger when the user presses Enter? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but just to be sure, in my Racket program, I just want to get a string "Y" or "N" back from the GUI. I tried using the message-box and it looks very handy because it paused program execution till I hit yes or no, but it would be great if I can make the program understand which button is being clicked. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Functional programming is so different, but interesting. Thanks for your help.